# Finding Least value of a function

Tags: functions

Let $ f $ be a one to one function from the set of natural numbers to itself such that $$f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$$ for all natural numbers $m$ and $n$  What is the least possible value of $$f(999)$$

I haven't encountered any problem of these kind ever before, any suggestion o how to do it are welcome.

Comment: Where is the scope of improvement in my question?

Comment: Just ignore them. I just undid it.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help

Comment: Functions that satisfy this property are called [completely multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function). They satisfy that if $n=p_1^{a_1}...p_m^{a_m}$ for $p_1,...,p_m$ different primes, then $f(n)=f(p_1)^{a_1}...f(p_m)^{a_m}$. So, $f(999)=f(3^3\cdot 37)=f(3)^3f(37)$. Now, since they say that $f$ is injective, then its values at the primes must be different and different from $0$ and $1$. So, we can define $f(3)=2$ and $f(37)=3$ to get the smallest value.

Comment: Then, to show that there is actually such an $f$, you can finish defining $f$ at the $n$-th prime $p_n\neq 3,37$ to be the $n$-th prime different from $2$ and $3$. The fundamental theorem of arithmetic gives you that such $f$ is injective.

Comment: This was the answer k was looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103809/discussion-between-howard-dickson-and-oscarrascal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to define for each prime $$p,f(p)=q$$ where $q$ is a number and $q$ can be defined to be a prime

But $q$ cannot be 1 as then $$ f(p^2) =f(p)=1$$which is not unique.

Now,$$f(999)=f(3^3×37)$$
This is lowest when we define
$$f(3)=2 , f(37)=3$$ that is, giving lest values to them.

Substituting we get the answer as 24

Answer (score 0):

Hint: in order to define your function, it is sufficient to define it on prime numbers (and on $x=1$, but that's trivially $f(1)=1$). Of course, there is injectivity to respect.